# Telerik RadGrid ExportToWord() - what happens in the background

Tags: c#, post, telerik, export, radgrid

What's happening in the background when `ExportToWord()` is called on a Telerik RadGrid?

For me, the page just reloads. The POST headers and response are the same (except from the viewstate which is empty) as they are when I just load the page.

Should there not be a different content type etc?

Comment: any way to debug the telerik sources? it tells me that symbols aren't loaded - do are they available?

Comment: OK, they are in the 'my account' section on their website